# How to build a keyword search volume using youtube APIs

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been assigned the task of building a keyword search volume feature using YouTube APIs. The goal is to enable users to input a keyword, and in response, receive a list of related words commonly searched on YouTube, along with their estimated monthly search volume. However, while I have explored the YouTube API documentation, I have only managed to retrieve video titles related to the given keyword.

To achieve the desired functionality, I need to find a way to estimate keyword search volume on YouTube.

I tried using the YouTube API to build a keyword search volume feature. I expected to get both video titles and search volume data for the given keyword. However, the API only returned video titles and didn't provide search volume directly.

Any other tool, APIs, or approaches that would allow me to retrieve search volume data for a given keyword on YouTube given that Youtube API does not support this?

Comment: the YouTube API doesn't support this

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Could you please suggest any other tools, APIs, or approaches that would allow me to retrieve search volume data for a given keyword on YouTube?